# JQ map and merge

Tags: json, jq

When I group and add (read merge) objects based on a value I would like to have certain attributes be concatenated together instead of the default "object on the right wins" behavior.

[demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7wVBGZ3crWs)

Put another way I would like the addition/merge of these two objects

```
[
  {
    "location": "apc1",
    "type": "app",
    "fgrp": "cert-apc-1"
  },
  {
    "location": "apc1",
    "type": "ctl",
    "cgrp": "ctl-apc1"
  }
]
```

to produce this

```
[
  {
    "location": "apc1",
    "type": "app,ctl",
    "fgrp": "cert-apc-1",
    "cgrp": "ctl-apc1"
  }
]
```

Attempted `group_by(.location) | map(add)` but as noted it basically just keeps the last value.  Also looked at transpose but was unsure it would meet the requirement.  Also, I'm not married to a comma as a delimiter if something else is easier.

Comment: Seems like `group_by` and then `join`ing those fields you want to combine.

Comment: If you want to concatenate string fields of matching keys, why doesn't `.location` then contain `"apc1,apc1"`? Is it because both parts are equal? Is it because `.location` as a key should be treated differently? Please specify.

Comment: Have the []'s and code attempted added.

Comment: @pmf that's the rub.  `map(add)` works just fine EXCEPT for the 'type' field.  Hopefully my latest corrections clarify things

Answer (score 2):

You could write your custom merge operation. For instance, iterate over all items, then over each item's fields, and collect all values in an array under the field's name under the according `.location` value. Finally, repair the `.location` arrays by replacing them with only their `first` item:

```bash
reduce .[] as $item ({};
  reduce ($item | to_entries[]) as $ent (.;
    .[$item.location][$ent.key] += [$ent.value]
  )
) | map(.location |= first)
```

```json
[
  {
    "location": "apc1",
    "type": [
      "app",
      "ctl"
    ],
    "fgrp": [
      "cert-apc-1"
    ],
    "cgrp": [
      "ctl-apc1"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1KK5CR1DIIQ)

Going further, you could concatenate the array values using `join` with a glue string (here `","`). Before that, prep the reparation of `.location` to match the type requirements of `join` (which only accepts arrays):

```bash
reduce .[] as $item ({};
  reduce ($item | to_entries[]) as $ent (.;
    .[$item.location][$ent.key] += [$ent.value]
  )
) | map(.location |= [first] | .[] |= join(","))
```

```json
[
  {
    "location": "apc1",
    "type": "app,ctl",
    "fgrp": "cert-apc-1",
    "cgrp": "ctl-apc1"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/C8VlLnSnkw7)

For convenience, you can now wrap this filter into a function definition with its dynamic parts (the index and join expressions) parametrized:

```bash
def merge(idx_expr; join_expr):
  reduce .[] as $item ({};
    reduce ($item | to_entries[]) as $ent (.;
      .[$item | idx_expr][$ent.key] += [$ent.value]
    )
  ) | map(join_expr);

merge(.location; .location |= [first] | .[] |= join(","))
```

```json
[
  {
    "location": "apc1",
    "type": "app,ctl",
    "fgrp": "cert-apc-1",
    "cgrp": "ctl-apc1"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/aKdPUdftfEC)

Or give your function a more general-purpose character by excluding the final mapping from it, so it produces an object (not an array) with the indices as keys, thus acting more like an array-valued variant of `group_by` (also making no distinction in processing regarding the indexed field, which after all could be any index expression, not just the value of one common field):

```bash
def merge_by(f):
  reduce .[] as $item ({};
    reduce ($item | to_entries[]) as $ent (.;
      .[$item|f][$ent.key] += [$ent.value]
    )
  );

merge_by(.location)
```

```json
{
  "apc1": {
    "location": [
      "apc1",
      "apc1"
    ],
    "type": [
      "app",
      "ctl"
    ],
    "fgrp": [
      "cert-apc-1"
    ],
    "cgrp": [
      "ctl-apc1"
    ]
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/hmK_1Xo9HRe)

Comment: Whoa...as always your answers never disappoint. You're like jq version of John Wick.

Answer (score 0):

> Attempted `group_by(.location) | map(add)` but as noted it basically just keeps the last value.

Following this more functional `group_by`-based approach, you could replace `add` with a custom function that first decomposes its input array (of grouped objects) into a stream of path-value pairs, then flips the first two positions in every path array (from [position, field name] to [field name, position]), and reomposes it again. The result is a single object (the field names moved to first position) with its items containing maps of that field's values across the group (with `null` (or a shorter array) at positions where the corresponing item did not have that field). Thus, a subsequent `join` would also require the arrays to be reduced to only contain non-null `values`:

```bash
def merge: fromstream(tostream | first[:2] |= reverse)
  | .location |= .[:1] | .[] |= (map(values) | join(","));

group_by(.location) | map(merge)
```

```json
[
  {
    "location": "apc1",
    "type": "app,ctl",
    "fgrp": "cert-apc-1",
    "cgrp": "ctl-apc1"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AjcJwZqEmOU)

Comment: Again, simply amazing.  Now the dilemma is which of these two wonderful approaches do I use.  

One question  what's the advantage of declaring a function over simply wrapping the `fromstream` in the `map(...)`?

Comment: Declaring a function can render your code more readable (if you are giving your function a meaningful name), and more succinct (if you needed that function more than just once). Note that the latter versions in my other answer also define functions; the main difference to this one is the separate iterations inside `group_by` and `map` as opposed to just one using the other approach(es). I just added this to provide one as close as possible to your original attempt, because using `group_by` might have been a hard(er) prerequisite for your goals (eg. when modifying an already existing pipeline).